# Accessing external resources with C#

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a wpf application where I want to hide some of the code complexity by creating resource dictionaries. 
I have an external file called "*SubFolder\LoginPanel.xaml*".
I created it as a resource dictionary, and added the reference to the App.xaml file.

In LoginPanel.xaml I have some custom colors defined, brushes, and two storyboards, *sbShowLoginMenu*, *sbHideLoginMenu*. 
In my MainWindow.xaml I can reference the defined brushes without any problems. However, I want to access my storyboards as well, but from C# code behind for mouse enter.

If I copy the story boards to the MainWindow.xaml file the storyboard works correctly, if I remove it from MainWindow.xaml it does not see the resource. It only sees the resources defined in the MainWindow.xaml.
My question is how do I get my code to work so that I can access the storyboard items from the resource dictionary?

My guess is that I have to add something to the '*Window*' tag such as xmlns:rd="clr-namespace:LoginPanel". I know this is not the right syntax but I could not find any documentation for this type of problem.

EDIT: When I try **var sb = FindResource("sbShowLoginMenu")**, the debugger returns 'resource not found.'.

Comment: Have you tries var sb = Application.Current.FindResource("sbShowLoginMenu") ? this should get you your resources which are specified in app.xaml

Comment: You may need to add the external ResourceDictionary to the [MergedDictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx) of your MainWindow's Resources.

Comment: @adminSoftDK, thank you for the suggestion. This did not work either, I still get the resources not found.

Comment: @Clemens I am not certain what you are asking. When I try to relocate the ResourceDictionary to my MainWindow.xaml I get an error stating that 'Resources can only be set once'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I was able to craft a search criteria that gives the right answer.
[Storyboards in ResourceDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543109/storyboards-in-resourcedictionary)

Basically storyboards are stateful objects and cannot be placed in a resource dictionary.